# Will sub-folder contents be restored under respective sub-folders?

Tags: google-drive

My wife's hard drive crashed recently with a bunch of pictures in sub-folders under the Pictures Library. IF they had been backed up with Google Drive, would they have restored with all pix in respective sub-folders?
Fortunately (to some degree)all were on a Photo Stick, so they were not lost, but they were all restored under one huge file! She is now spending hours sorting them out.
Don't want having to do this again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Google Drive keeps all the sub-folders when making a backup.

I assume you're talking about `C:\Users\Bill\Pictures`. In that case, [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) would sync that folder to your "Computers" tab. In that tab, you will find a folder with the name that Google Drive assigns to your computer (you can edit the name), and in that folder, you will find the Pictures folder, as well as the Documents folder and/or Desktop folder.

You can *add* those folders to My Drive so that they appear in the main section of Google Drive—then they will be located in both the Computers tab and the My Drive tab.

Personally, I prefer to keep all my files (photographs included) in My Drive, then I sync that folder with `C:\Users\ahorn\Documents\My Drive` across the few computers I use. So, I don't use the "Computers" tab anymore, as I have reset and changed computers so many times that the number of computers would have started to pile up.

Comment: OK, thanks very much for the response!

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please upvote or 'accept' it by clicking the tick below the voting buttons. Thanks

Comment: Clicked on the up arrow, but not sure if it registered.

Comment: No, the upvote didn't register. Please accept your favourite answer as well, by clicking on the tick below the voting buttons. :)